# Can a Cassandra keyspace be created using the java driver (from DataStax)?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Is it possible to setup Cassandra using the DataStax java driver (create the KeySpace, create a Table, etc.)?

In the [Getting Started ...](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-cassandra-and-java-part-i?unit=2201) documentation, it's assumed that the KeySpace, etc. were created interactively, using cqlsh.  I strongly prefer to do *everything* in java, but looking through the java driver api, I didn't find a way to create a KeySpace.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

In case you're looking for the corresponding methods within the driver's fluent API:

```
SchemaStatement stmnt = SchemaBuilder.createKeyspace("test")
        .with()
        .replication(ImmutableMap.of("class", "SimpleStrategy", "replication_factor", 3));
session.execute(stmnt);
```

Will result in:

```
cqlsh> describe keyspace test;

CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '3'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to setup Cassandra using the DataStax java driver (create the KeySpace, create a Table, etc.)?

Of course:

```
Session session = ...

session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE ....");
session.execute("CREATE TABLE ...");
```